# Nhibernate - How do I get ordered distinct results with QueryOver?

Tags: nhibernate

```
public class City
{
    virtual public long Id { get; set; }
    virtual public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

City table contains duplicated Names and I want to remove duplicates. I also want the results to be ordered by Id.

First I thought about the following query.

```
select distinct Name from City order by Id;
```

But this breaks with 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.' exception. After seeing http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx I think I should do:

```
select Name from City group by Name order by min(Id)
```

So my question is how can I do this query with QueryOver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible in ICriteria:

```
var list =
    session.CreateCriteria<City>()
        .SetProjection(Projections.Group("Name"))
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc(Projections.Min("Id")))
        .List<string>();
```

But this is not currently possible in QueryOver, because the .OrderBy(IProjection) overload is missing.  Once the missing overload has been added it should look something like:

```
var list =
    s.QueryOver<City>()
        .Select(Projections.Group<City>(p => p.Name))
        .OrderBy(Projections.Min<City>(c => c.Id)).Asc
        .List<string>();
```

Note that the Projections overloads are there just now, so you can write the following (typesafe) query in ICriteria:

```
var list =
    session.CreateCriteria<City>()
        .SetProjection(Projections.Group<City>(c => c.Name))
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc(Projections.Min<City>(c => c.Id)))
        .List<string>();
```

Comment: FYI, the missing overload for .OrderBy has been added to the trunk, and will appear in RC1.

Comment: Hi FlukeFan => So the 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.' exception should no longer appear?

Answer (score 0):

So, what I've found is pretty simple...

```
var query = session.QueryOver<MyModel>()
            // Conditions here
            .OrderBy(m => m.GetThisDistinctField).Desc()  // ...or Asc()...
            .SelectList(m => m.SelectGroup(g => g.GetThisDistinctField));

var result = query.List<FieldDataType>().ToList();
return result;
```

To get an ordered query in queryover, start with a query that includes whatever criteria you need, but then add the `SelectList`/`SelectGroup` setup in order to get the distinct list.  In other words, it's sort of like NHibernate can take a regular query, and then do special stuff to make it a `select distinct` query.

This is a solution I'm using in a current project I'm working on; I hope it helps someone else too.